# iOS - Show push pop-up and play sound of the push without actual push

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, push

I want functionality in my app which will show the user how the push will look like.
So I want to show push notification and play sound  from app code and even without internet connection.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does using a [Local Notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) help at all?  This is similar to a push notification but doesn't need a server.

Other than that you can do it yousefl but you would have to do all of the drawing code!